# How to open form2 from form1 (from async task)

Tags: c#, forms

I'm trying to open form2 from an async task in form1.
When I try to open it using:

```
public void DoWorkPollingTask()
{
    Form f2 = new Form2();
    Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    f2.Show();

                    await Task.Delay(10000);
                }
            });
}
```

it shows me this:
[image]

Please don't be confused about that Internet Connection Error. It's not an actual popup from visual studio, it's just my form2, but the problem is, it's not completely loaded as you can see on that image. It should look like this:
[image]

Is there any way I can show form2 from a task timer task that runs every x seconds?

Comment: Code: https://hastebin.com/ehulavotoj.cs

Comment: Rather use modal form: `f2.ShowDialog()` without any task.

Comment: @OpenSource , can you explain why are you using while(true) and Task.Delay beceause it's frezze your UI , it make no sense for me .

Comment: @sayahimad Why would you think it would freeze the UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access UI elements from the non-UI thread, and that's imply going to cause lots of problems.

Simply *don't* use a thread pool thread, as there's no reason to do so here at all.

```
public async void DoWorkPollingTask()
{
    Form f2 = new Form2();
    while (true)
    {
        f2.Show();

        await Task.Delay(10000);
    }
}
```

> Is there any way I can show form2 from a task timer task that runs every x seconds?

You could use an *actual* timer, if you prefer.  The code is already very simple, but if you simply prefer using a timer, then use a timer.  Just make sure you use a timer designed to work with a UI framework, rather than one of the system timers, so that it'll fire the event in the UI thread.